# Swift5(+RxSwift) 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

Tags: swift, xcode, rx-swift

I'm learning MVVM + RxSwift.
I would like to save a value to reuse it at the next flow.
But I encountered the error above.

I assume I initialised the value which is "translatedText" but the error still comes up.

I have tried some ways that were to initialise with the declaration and so on...

```swift
import UIKit
import RxSwift

final class ViewModel {


    private let api: apiProtocol
    let validationText: Observable<String>
    let getObservable: Observable<String>
    var translatedText: String
    // var translatedText: String = "" //this case also dosn't work

    init(inputObservable: Observable<String?>, changeButtonClicked: Observable<Void>, model: ModelProtocol, api: apiProtocol = APICntl()) {

        self.api = api
        self.translatedText = "" //I guess I initialised this here

        let event = inputObservable
            .flatMap { input -> Observable<Event<Void>> in
                if let text = input {
                    self.translatedText = text // error. i want to save "input" to use at "let tapEvent"
                }
                return model
                    .validate(text: input)
                    .materialize()
            }
            .share()

        self.validationText = event
            .flatMap { event -> Observable<String> in
                switch event {
                case .next:
                    return .just("")
                case let .error(error as ModelError):
                    return .just(error.errorLabel)
                case .error, .completed:
                    return .empty()
                }
            }
            .startWith(ModelError.invalidBlank.errorLabel)

        let tapEvent = changeButtonClicked
            .flatMap { (result) -> Observable<Event<String>> in
                return api
                    .fetch(text: self.translatedText) // I want use it here
                    .materialize()
        }
        .share()

        self.getObservable = tapEvent
            .flatMap { event -> Observable<String> in
                switch event {
                case .next:
                    return .just(event.element!)
                case let .error(error as ModelError):
                    return .just(error.errorLabel)
                case .error, .completed:
                    return .empty()
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Do you guys have any better solutions?

----- self solution -----

I just simply created a temp variable before let event and it works as I want.

```swift
final class ViewModel {


    private let api: apiProtocol
    let validationText: Observable<String>
    let getObservable: Observable<String>

    init(inputObservable: Observable<String?>, changeButtonClicked: Observable<Void>, model: ModelProtocol, api: apiProtocol = APICntl()) {

        self.api = api
        var temp = ""

        let event = inputObservable
            .flatMap { input -> Observable<Event<Void>> in
                if let text = input {
                    temp = text
                }
                return model
                    .validate(text: input)
                    .materialize()
            }
            .share()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't tie two independent observable streams to each other with some random block of "temp" memory. The two streams depend on `inputObservable` and that should be made clear. Also, your view model can be greatly simplified...

```
final class ViewModel {
    let validationText: Observable<String>
    let getObservable: Observable<String>

    init(inputObservable: Observable<String?>, changeButtonClicked: Observable<Void>, model: ModelProtocol, api: apiProtocol = APICntl()) {

        let translatedText = inputObservable.share() // this line is unnecessary if `inputObservable` is already hot.

        self.validationText = translatedText
            .flatMap { input in
                return model
                    .validate(text: input)
                    .map { "" }
                    .catchError { error in .just((error as? ModelError)?.errorLabel ?? error.localizedDescription) }
            }
            .startWith(ModelError.invalidBlank.errorLabel)

        self.getObservable = changeButtonClicked
            .withLatestFrom(translatedText)
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .flatMap { translatedText in
                return api
                    .fetch(text: translatedText)
                    .catchError { error in .just((error as? ModelError)?.errorLabel ?? error.localizedDescription) }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `self` is not *completely* initialized when you call `flatMap`. In your case, `validationText` and `getObservable` are in an undefined state.

The quickest way would be to make them implicitly unwrapped optionals, but you really have to guarantee that they are not being accessed before being initialized:

```
final class ViewModel {


    private let api: apiProtocol
    let validationText: Observable<String>!
    let getObservable: Observable<String>!
    var translatedText: String!

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
these two are initialised by `self.validationText = event` and `self.getObservable = tapEvent` so that the problems was that `self` was used in a closure as `self.translatedText` before it is initialised.

But I could solve it by simply doing code above.

I found another way to use `lazy` but it is not for this time.

Comment: You should avoid doing this if you want your app to be crashfree.

Answer (score 0):

---- self solution -----

I just simply created a temp variable before let event and it works as I want.

```swift
final class ViewModel {


    private let api: apiProtocol
    let validationText: Observable<String>
    let getObservable: Observable<String>

    init(inputObservable: Observable<String?>, changeButtonClicked: Observable<Void>, model: ModelProtocol, api: apiProtocol = APICntl()) {

        self.api = api
        var temp = ""

        let event = inputObservable
            .flatMap { input -> Observable<Event<Void>> in
                if let text = input {
                    temp = text
                }
                return model
                    .validate(text: input)
                    .materialize()
            }
            .share()
```